Problem in adding option inside haproxy backend
This is what the backend I want is like
backend backend_name1
   mode http
   option httpchk
   option forwarded

The key code with data-plane-api to add the backend is
url = f'{host}/v2/services/haproxy/configuration/backends?transaction_id={transaction_id}'
payload = {
 "name": backend_name,
 "mode": 'http',
 "option": "httpchk"
}
session.post(url,json=payload,timeout=API_CALL_TIME_OUT_NORMAL_VALUE)

However, the option httpchk is not added, I don't know what is the correct way to add option in backend
